# What is the best way to have indexing in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

Seems like small question, but i am puzzled.

I have a table with around 25 columns. The table will contains > 100k rows at any point of time. 
I want to run below query continuously in loop.

```
SELECT recordfile
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE duration = '0'
AND attempt < max_attempt
AND thread =1
ORDER BY id ASC
```

It looks like query is taking too much time (0.0150 secs on avg). How to put proper indexing or any other method, to make the query optimally quick?

Comment: Why do you say 0.015 s is "more time"? Was it running even with lesser time before? Do you already have any indexing in place for this table?

Comment: I am expecting in the range of 0.0005, which i am getting in other table, some other query. Since it need to fetch the row and send it to next process, I am saying its slow. I gave index for id and another index for duration, attempt and max-attempt.

Comment: 0.015 seems fine in general, and we cannot beat that without more details about your data distribution. If e.g. only 2 out of 2 million rows have duration = 0, an index on duration suffices; if not, then not. If 5 million rows fit your condition, just sending those takes ages. (I guess that max_attempt-attempt is most relevant, and you might need to redesing it to be able to index that). In general, "need 0.0005s" and "continous loop" rings a lot of alarm bells though (e.g. that you may want to run it 2000 times per s.) There might be better ways to do what you are trying to achieve there.

Answer (score 1):

Are `attempt` and `max_attempt` both columns in the table?  I'll assume they are.

Does the processing then change some of those columns?

Add this:

```
INDEX(thread, duration,  -- in either order
      id)
```

Grab 100 rows at a time, not just one.  Then, as you process them, double check the columns that might have changed.  The 'grab' will be a little slower (but not 100x); the test might be a lot faster.  Be sure to devise an optimal index for *that* test.